# Parameterizing sql in vb

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameterized

I have this module call Procedure , and I want to parametrize it. I'm sending a string as the query  to the procedure module . I look already in google but I could not find the answer to my problem.

```
Procedures.Insert("INSERT INTO Technician (tec_name, tec_email, rol_id) VALUES ('" & txt_tech.text & "',  '" & txt_tech_email.text & "', " & cbo_tech_role.selectvalue.tostring & ")", "Technican Add Correct")
```

========================================
I will probably change it for .....

```
Procedures.Insert("INSERT INTO Technician (tec_name, tec_email, rol_id) VALUES ('@tech_name',  '@tech_email', '@tech_role' ")", "Technican Add Correct")
```

================ But I dont know where I can Parametrized

```
 Public Sub Insert(query As String, msg As String)
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(cs)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        cn.Open()
        With cmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query
            .Connection = cn
            .Parameters.AddValueWith("@tech_name",txt_tech_name.text)
            .Parameters.AddValueWith("@tech_email",txt_tech_email.text)
            .Parameters.AddValueWith("@tech_rol",txt_tech_role.selectValue.tostring)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        MessageBox.Show(msg, "INSERT", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString, ".  :  :    ERROR    :  :  .", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        If cn IsNot Nothing AndAlso cn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.Close()
            cn = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Because I have a module that is separate from the main code , I'm not able to call the textboxes because they are separate from the main module  ... any idea on how to do this ??  ... Dont be hard .. This is my 14 week working with VB.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the `Insert` function parameter for SqlParameters

```vb
Public Sub Insert(query As String, msg As String, params As SqlParameter())
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(cs)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        cn.Open()
        With cmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query
            .Connection = cn
            If params IsNot Nothing AndAlso params.Count > 0 Then
                .Parameters.AddRange(params)
            End If
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        MessageBox.Show(msg, 
                        "INSERT", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString, ".  :  :    ERROR    :  :  .",
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                       MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        If cn IsNot Nothing AndAlso cn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.Close()
            cn = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Then use it like this:

```vb
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Technician (tec_name, tec_email, rol_id) VALUES (@tech_name, @tech_email, @tech_role)"
Dim msg As String = "Technican Add Correct"
Dim params As SqlParameter() = {New SqlParameter("@tech_name",txt_tech_name.text),
                                New SqlParameter("@tech_email",txt_tech_email.text),
                                New SqlParameter("@tech_rol",txt_tech_role.selectValue.tostring)}

Procedures.Insert(query, msg, params)
```

Using array of `SqlParameter` give you a possibility for using same function with parameter type other then `string`

Answer (score 0):

You can have it this way... it works for me.

```
        String query = "INSERT INTO Technician(tec_name, tec_email, rol_id) VALUES(@tech_name, @tech_email, @tech_rolr)"
        params = {"tech_name", "tech_email", "tech_rolr"}
        values = {"" & txt_tech_name.text, "" & txt_tech_email.text, "" & txt_tech_role.selectValue.tostring()}

        SaveUpdateDelete(query, params, values)
```

under module, you can put this

```
    Public params() As String
    Public values() As String

    Public Sub SaveUpdateDelete(ByVal sql As String, ByVal parameters() As String, ByVal Values() As String)
      If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
          con.Close()
      End If
      con.Open()
      command = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)

      For i = 0 To parameters.Count - 1
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & parameters(i).ToString, Values(i))
      Next
      command.CommandText = sql
      command.ExecuteNonQuery()

      con.Close()
    End Sub
```

the method `SaveUpdateDelete` is applicable for **adding**, **updating** and **deleting** data.. your code will only differ in query... *"insert, update, delete"*